# "top" "ps aux" "dmesg" "ls -la" and other command do not run, freeze console, server is running properly otherwise

Tags: linux, command-line

Never seen an issue like this. I have 2 webservers that do not allow me to run `ls -la` on them, but they do run `ls` properly. I can't run `top`, `ps aux`, `dmesg` commands either. I can run `ps` but if I add `aux` I get frozen out. When I try to run those my SSH connection just freezes. Basically, I can't cancel out of the command and have to restart my SSH session.

I can go through the system using `ls` and `less` and try to go through log files, but I can't find an issue. Utilization on the system is working and the webservers are functioning.

Any ideas?

Comment: The nuclear option is running those commands under `strace` to see what system calls cause the apparent hang.

Comment: Good idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, `strace` doesn't run on the system either.

Comment: what system is that?

Comment: The issue turned out to be a problem with MTU. Commands were able to run locally on the system, but not through SSH. Lowering MTU has resolved the issue for now.